# Enzyme React test trouble with mapping components

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am attempting to write an enzyme test for a react component. I want to test that, when I give this component a prop of "items," the component contains a "ToDoItem" as shown mapped below. I can't figure out how to test the presence of the ToDoItem component.

Here is the component:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ToDoItem from '../ToDoItem/ToDoItem';

export default class ToDos extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const toDoItems = this.props.items.map((item, key) => (
            <ToDoItem 
                item={item} 
                key={key} 
                onDelete={value => this.props.onDelete(value)}
                onCheck={value => this.props.onCheck(value)}
            />
        )); 

        return (
            <section className="g-column"> 
                <div className="g-item-title">
                    <h3 className="g-title">Tasks</h3>
                </div>
                { toDoItems }   
            </section>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the enzyme test. This fails:

```
it('contains to ToDoItem when passed props', () => {
    const toDos = mount(<ToDos items={["example"]} />); 
    expect(toDos.find(<ToDoItem />)).toEqual(true)
});
```

I've tried adding the full mapped item in the expect statement:

this.props.onDelete(value)} onCheck={value => this.props.onCheck(value)} />

This does not work either. Help!

Comment: I'm sorry if it took sometime from the community to reply, but I've replied to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This worked:

```
it('displays ToDoItem if passed props', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<ToDos items={['example']} />);
        expect(wrapper.find('ToDoItem').exists()).toEqual(true);   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**You should never add key as the index of the array**. I'm writing that in bold because it causes mistakes when you remove an item from the array and react doesn't have track of that and hence your test fails.

There's even a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYdNmD3GJ1E) about it.

Instead of using the index, you can use an identifier / id like this:

```
    const toDoItems = this.props.items.map((item, index) => (
        <ToDoItem 
            item={item} 
            key={item.id} // this is your id string
            onDelete={value => this.props.onDelete(value)}
            onCheck={value => this.props.onCheck(value)}
        />
    ));
```

Which will help react keep track of the component.

Comment: Good to know. That wasn't the problem, but I appreciate the advice

Comment: @DakshMiglani Missing keys gives warnings, I'd like to test that a component was invoked with a key. A key doesn't become a prop, it kind of disappears on the way. What would a test like that look like?

Comment: @miphe you can't actually. React doesn't expose that. there is a way to do that tho, but it's kinda hacky and can break: `this._reactInternalFiber.key`

Comment: Fair enough, thanks a lot. I will simply have to test things around it, like the data I use to build the key.